# NServiceBus: How do I extend scale for a decimal column?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

We are using decimal numbers with a scale of six decimals, ie 1.123456. Now as we are using NServiceBus and we need to persist this value in our saga data we got trouble.

When we are returning to the saga and picks up our value again, the value is 1.12345. I haven't found anyone having the same problem but I guess this can't be a unique case.

My saga data looks kind of,

```
public class MySagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Originator { get; set; }
    public virtual string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

The case is that when Property2 is 1.123456 and it is persisted in my saga, returning to the saga and pick it up then Property2 is 1.12345.

I know why it is happening, NHibernate creates a database field, `DECIMAL(19, 5)`, but I don't know how to resolve my problem. I don't want to create the table myself but let NServiceBus do it for me.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to create a custom dialect for NHibernate if you want to change the way decimals are mapped by default. For example if your using SQL server have a look at MsSql2000Dialect.cs in the Nhibernate source code. You can see it defines a decimal column like this:

```
RegisterColumnType(DbType.Decimal, "DECIMAL(19,5)");
```

You can see an example of how to do it here in java. It's basically the same in C#
http://shashivelur.com/blog/2008/08/override-hibernate-sql-types-mapping/

Once you've created your custom dialect you just need to set it up in your NHibernate config:

```
nhCibfig.SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(MyCustomDecimalDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

or

```
<property name="dialect">MyAssembly.MyCustomDecimalDialect, MyAssembly</property>
```

Comment: Well, is this the only solution? I was actually hoping for only adding an attribute to my property... Since NHibernate is encapsulated in NServiceBus I was hoping for a better solution than to go to NHibernate source code.... or just changing the datatype in Sql Server, which I tried with success.

Comment: You can't define column mappings using attributes with just NHibernate alone. Your solution of changing the datatype manually will work but it does solve the problem of having nservicebus/nhibernate create the table for you.